# Is this function getting assigned as a method or already executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Coming from C++ and Java, I am a beginner with Javascript. This code pattern confuses me (found in a jQuery Application):

```
var opts = { drop : empty};

function drop(arg){
    opts.drop(arg);
    //do something
}
```

How I would read this: 
The object `opts` is created and the attribute `drop` is declared, but initialized as empty.
Then, the function(-object) `drop` is defined. In the second line, the drop-attribute of the opts object is called as a method. But, in my understanding, `opts.drop` is empty. So it should not be callable.

What happens here? Am I missing some important code, or is this a pattern that makes sense?

EDIT: Source: https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop/blob/master/jquery.filedrop.js

Comment: `opts.drop` is not "empty". `empty` is an identifier. That means it could be another function, variable, number, boolean, anything. We can't tell what it is exactly because we can't see where `empty` was defined in the code you've shown, but it's not that important.

Comment: `opts.drop` can be redefined at any point, so initializing the `drop` function like this is not problematic. You'll only get an error when you call `drop()` and `opts.drop` is not callable.

Comment: Try: `alert(typeof empty);`. If it shows `"function"`, you've nothing to be worried about. In JavaScript, functions are first class objects. They can be passed around as data just like any other object. In fact, you can even add properties to them and define other methods on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`empty` is likely the name of a function, which is implemented like:

```
function empty () {}
```

If it were `null`, `undefined`, a string, an object, an array, etc...  ...then there'd be reason to be concerned, because that would end poorly.

But my gut tells me that if you look for its definition, `empty === function () {}`

For added confusion, if `empty` is defined as an assignment:

```
var empty = function () {};
```

That assignment must happen above where it's being referenced in `opts`.

If, however, it's a declaration:

```
function empty () {}
```

that function could be declared anywhere, including the bottom of the script, because function-declarations are compiled before anything else in the script.

***EDIT***

Doing a quick check, I'm seeing a few different `empty` functions at different scopes.
Some are removing callbacks from an array (by setting the array to an empty one), some are removing HTML elements from a parent, and some are checking if an element has any child elements.

Of course, I'm viewing the minified source from this site, so there may be more `empty` functions out there.

Comment: You are right, I now found the declaration of empty. So I guess I now understand what is happening here: The global drop is indeed a different function than the method opts.drop which can probably be changed _optionally_ somewhere else. With this pattern, whenever drop(arg) is called, opts.drop(e) is also called, providing the user of the library with an anchor to insert his own code as a plugin.

Comment: "Of course, I'm viewing the minified source from this site". What site are you referring to?

Comment: @Konstantin Stackoverflow.  It uses a minified version of jQuery, which it downloads from Google's CDN, it seems.

Comment: I was talking about different code, the link to the source is here: https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop/blob/master/jquery.filedrop.js

Comment: Aha.  I was even right the first time -- in that file, `empty` really is just empty.

Comment: Actually, in this case, `empty` is a failover.  I'm just getting home from work at midnight (hooray), but I read through the code and basically what is happening is this: the default options have all of the custom-events (by custom, I mean non-DOM) set to a null function. When you create a new object, you send in user-defined options. The program then uses jQuery's `extend` method (copies properties to the first object, from the rest of the objects in the call -- simple enumerate and assign pointers to the same property name). `.extend({}, defaultOptions, options)`.

Comment: So if `options` contains a method, being the last in line, the new object will reference that method. If `options` doesn't have that method, then the object still has a `default` event, which just does nothing. It allows for really sloppy coding, but it also prevents fatal errors, trying to call `undefined(args);` Personally, I wouldn't consider something a hook unless it supported the ability for me to "hijack" or "piggyback" code in some way. `empty` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, you worded it very well.

Answer (score 1):

We can conclude that empty is not just a variable by looking at this

```
opts.drop(arg);
```

Here the drop is actually being passed a argument so ,

**empty** is a function that takes in 1 argument..

So `var opts = { drop : empty};`  // is nothing but

```
var opts = { drop : function(argument) {} };
```